# Соотносительное слово в СПП

Tags: синтаксис

Может ли быть в качестве соотносительного слова указательное местоимение "этот" в придаточных определительных? (Я встречала только предложения, где выделяют в качестве соотносительного слова указательное местоимение "тот"). И если да, то от него будет задаваться вопрос к придаточному, то есть над ним будет знак × ?

"... Этот человек с добрыми, умными глазами,который рассказывал им с таким чистосердечием..." (А. П. Чехов "О любви")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"... Этот человек с добрыми, умными глазами, который рассказывал им с таким чистосердечием..."

Нет, в данном случае определительное придаточное связано с главным только **союзным словом КОТОРЫЙ**,  соотносительное слово отсутствует, так как здесь **не является обязательным.** Опорным словом в главном предложении является существительное: человек (какой?) – который рассказывал им с таким чистосердечием..."

В СПП с придаточными определительными используются  соотносительные слова **ТОТ, ТАКОЙ**.

Местоимение ЭТОТ относится **с контексту**, оно указывает на персонажа, упомянутого ранее. Фактически  слово «человек» имеет три  определителя:  указательное местоимение ЭТОТ, несогласованное определение  в постпозиции и придаточное определительное предложение.